# Why do LCD monitors turn blue right before they switch off?

Tags: lcd

I occasionally observe the display of LCD monitors turn black then blue as they enter power savings mode. This appears to be the regular behaviour of many LCD monitors.

As the bright blue screen sometimes hurts my eyes, particularly in a dimly lit environment, I wonder why the vendors did not choose some other, more decent color? And more generally, why would the displays not silently enter power savings mode without any vivid behaviour?

Here's an example of one such monitor - an ASUS VN247 series. Note: Though the phone-cam didn't show this well, the screen is actually the same shade of blue all over (the shade seen on the outer edges), except the boxes in the middle. Inside the inner box, it says "HDMI1 NO INPUT". Upon loss of input, the monitor goes black for a couple seconds before displaying this screen for a couple seconds, then it goes to sleep.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, my experience has been the opposite. Most LCDs I've used turn black, perhaps with a small message noting that it's going into power-saving mode or has lost signal, just before going off. The only one I've had behave otherwise is the newest one on my home computer, an ASUS screen, which does as you describe. It's likely a vendor-specific configuration and, absent some commentary from someone who's actually responsible for such design, all you'll probably get from here is speculation.

Comment: It is actually blue, or just a bright white color with a bluish tint?    You understand how a LCD works?  A bright backlight, and then layers of LCD to filter out the light?  It sounds like the filtering component of your display is shutting off before the backlight.

Comment: @Zoredache Can't speak for the OP, but in my case it's *definitely* blue. I'll have to check when I get home to see if there's any other particulars (i.e.: on-screen messages I've forgotten) worth mentioning. If it's by design, it's really an odd choice. But mine's been this way since day 1 and I have no problems with it otherwise.

Comment: Its just a simple, stored image, and I suspect the single solid colour simply stores better. *My* asus ve208 does a black screen instead, as does my dell.

Comment: Like @Iszi's experience, my BENQ GW2460 monitor really turns blue like every blue subpixel shines.

Comment: @Iszi On Asus VS24AH it only turns blue when source is HDMI, on DVI it's black. That blue is annoying as heck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a stylistic choice made by the LCD controller designer.  The choice of the color blue is speculated on [this related UX question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56428/why-is-blue-used-as-a-background-color-to-indicate-no-signal) to be historically based in the generation of NTSC signals:

> The hue of a colored
>   object will depend upon the phase relationship with the reference
>   signal [...]
>   Yellow is the easiest hue to generate [...] but
>   blue is the second-easiest (exactly-opposite phase), and variations in
>   lightness and saturation are less noticeable with blue. Thus,
>   generation of a blue screen has technical advantages versus any other
>   color.